# How to place first item at start, then second item of column directly in center?

Tags: flutter

I think I am not seeing a simple solution to this, but I want to have purple icon and text at the same height as black icon, when I have purple divider in first example as first item
[image]

Here is how my code of this purple Column look like:

```
Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 4,
                  width: size.width * 0.22,
                  color: Colors.deepPurple,
                ),
                const Column(
                  children: [
                    Icon(
                      Icons.home,
                      color: Colors.deepPurple,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Strona główna',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.deepPurple
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

I tried using `Expanded` or `Spacer` but it didnt work for me.

Comment: Is this what you want? `https://i.stack.imgur.com/LW24A.png`

Comment: can you describe what you want to achieve?
Have you tried playing with the different alignments of columns? MainAxis and CrossAxis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the result you are looking for

[image]

You can use `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center` for the outer `Column` widget, and put the inner `Column` inside `Expanded` and `Padding`.

This is the code:

```dart
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, // Changed this!
  children: [
    Container(
      height: 4,
      width: size.width * 0.22,
      color: Colors.deepPurple,
    ),
    const Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 13.0), // Change this if not in the middle
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Icon(
              Icons.home,
              color: Colors.deepPurple,
            ),
            Text(
              'Strona główna',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```